# Basic confusion about residuals in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing some code for a class project that requires me to find the residuals of some data points and a fitted line to test its "fit"

I have been given this code:

```
p, residuals, rank, singular_values, rcond = np.polyfit(temp,voltage,degree,full=True)
```

but the residuals it gives me is a sum of the square of the residuals. 
If I want the residuals for each point, i.e the vertical distance between each plot and the fitted line, how can I do this?

Comment: Calculate the function in given point and subtract your point's value.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have these data points:

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(10)
y = 5*x + np.random.randn(10)
```

In your code, `p` gives you the coefficients of the fitted function:

```
p, residuals, rank, singular_values, rcond = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1, full=True)

p
Out: array([ 5.04994402,  0.36378617])
```

You can calculate the fitted points using those coefficients as follows:

```
y_hat = p[0]*x + p[1]  # add higher degree terms if needed
```

The same can be done with `np.polyval`:

```
y_hat = np.polyval(p, x)
```

The difference between `y`  and `y_hat`  will give you the residuals:

```
res = y - y_hat

res
Out: 
array([-0.30784646,  1.07050188,  0.34836945, -0.35403036, -0.01319629,
        0.01869734,  1.08284167, -0.56138505, -0.04556331, -1.23838885])
```

And if you want to check:

```
(res**2).sum() == residuals  # sum of squared errors
Out: array([ True], dtype=bool)
```